# como colocar 3 imagenes una encima de otra respetando su posición dentro de grid layout?

Tags: css, css-grid-layout, position

Tengo 3 imágenes que deben de ir una encima de otra obligatoriamente para ello uso las propiedades `position:absolute` y `z-index:121,z-index:137,z-index:140`, en cada imagen respetivamente, el problema es que tengo un grid-layout y las imágenes salen correctamente una encima de otra pero su posición es fija en la pantalla y yo deseo que guarde su posición dentro de su grid-area.

```css
body{
display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
        "hd"
        "mn"
        "ft"
}

header{
grid-area: hd;
}
main{
grid-area: mn;
}
main img#img1{
position:absolute;
z-index:121;
}
main img#img2{
position:absolute;
z-index:137;
}
main img#img3{
position:absolute;
z-index:140;
}
footer{
grid-area: ft;
}
```

```html
<body>
<header>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non placerat risus, in aliquet augue. Sed libero magna, sodales vel accumsan non, fringilla ac massa. Sed euismod rhoncus felis, sed ultricies metus consectetur ut. Etiam et felis a tortor feugiat sagittis id a ipsum. In consequat odio ut velit rutrum elementum. Nulla facilisi. Vivamus lacus turpis, viverra sed laoreet vel, tempus quis mi. Morbi a libero ac odio fermentum efficitur ut at est. Nulla id ex id orci ultrices ultrices. Suspendisse potenti. In ut nulla a sapien finibus interdum. Aenean feugiat eget urna vitae sodales. Nulla pharetra pharetra quam lacinia mattis. Vivamus pulvinar fringilla velit in viverra. Curabitur vel metus sed nunc pellentesque egestas vel ut nunc. Suspendisse potenti.

Cras at urna vel metus pretium porttitor. Pellentesque eget iaculis mi. Phasellus id lacinia odio. Curabitur vitae sem in lacus semper sagittis. Etiam molestie sem quis nisl ornare, ut dictum orci luctus. Quisque rutrum elit metus, sed elementum diam maximus et. Aliquam ornare, odio at egestas pharetra, ligula tellus euismod nibh, vel semper ligula velit eget ante. Cras vel consequat magna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Duis eget nisi tortor. Sed et interdum leo. Integer tempus ex non tortor hendrerit vulputate ut volutpat lacus.</p>
</header>
<main>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non placerat risus, in aliquet augue. Sed libero magna, sodales vel accumsan non, fringilla ac massa. Sed euismod rhoncus felis, sed ultricies metus consectetur ut. Etiam et felis a tortor feugiat sagittis id a ipsum. In consequat odio ut velit rutrum elementum. Nulla facilisi. Vivamus lacus turpis, viverra sed laoreet vel, tempus quis mi. Morbi a libero ac odio fermentum efficitur ut at est. Nulla id ex id orci ultrices ultrices. Suspendisse potenti. In ut nulla a sapien finibus interdum. Aenean feugiat eget urna vitae sodales. Nulla pharetra pharetra quam lacinia mattis. Vivamus pulvinar fringilla velit in viverra. Curabitur vel metus sed nunc pellentesque egestas vel ut nunc. Suspendisse potenti.

Cras at urna vel metus pretium porttitor. Pellentesque eget iaculis mi. Phasellus id lacinia odio. Curabitur vitae sem in lacus semper sagittis. Etiam molestie sem quis nisl ornare, ut dictum orci luctus. Quisque rutrum elit metus, sed elementum diam maximus et. Aliquam ornare, odio at egestas pharetra, ligula tellus euismod nibh, vel semper ligula velit eget ante. Cras vel consequat magna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Duis eget nisi tortor. Sed et interdum leo. Integer tempus ex non tortor hendrerit vulputate ut volutpat lacus.</p>
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/12/09/21/11/silhouette-5818603_960_720.jpg" id="img1">
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/12/09/21/11/silhouette-5818603_960_720.jpg" id="img2">
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/12/09/21/11/silhouette-5818603_960_720.jpg" id="img3">
</main>
<footer>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non placerat risus, in aliquet augue. Sed libero magna, sodales vel accumsan non, fringilla ac massa. Sed euismod rhoncus felis, sed ultricies metus consectetur ut. Etiam et felis a tortor feugiat sagittis id a ipsum. In consequat odio ut velit rutrum elementum. Nulla facilisi. Vivamus lacus turpis, viverra sed laoreet vel, tempus quis mi. Morbi a libero ac odio fermentum efficitur ut at est. Nulla id ex id orci ultrices ultrices. Suspendisse potenti. In ut nulla a sapien finibus interdum. Aenean feugiat eget urna vitae sodales. Nulla pharetra pharetra quam lacinia mattis. Vivamus pulvinar fringilla velit in viverra. Curabitur vel metus sed nunc pellentesque egestas vel ut nunc. Suspendisse potenti.

Cras at urna vel metus pretium porttitor. Pellentesque eget iaculis mi. Phasellus id lacinia odio. Curabitur vitae sem in lacus semper sagittis. Etiam molestie sem quis nisl ornare, ut dictum orci luctus. Quisque rutrum elit metus, sed elementum diam maximus et. Aliquam ornare, odio at egestas pharetra, ligula tellus euismod nibh, vel semper ligula velit eget ante. Cras vel consequat magna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Duis eget nisi tortor. Sed et interdum leo. Integer tempus ex non tortor hendrerit vulputate ut volutpat lacus.</p>
</footer>
</body>
```

Como podéis ver la imagen no respeta el grid layout ya que tiene una posición absoluta, se puede conseguir el mismo resultado, de una imagen sobre otra respetando su grid-layout??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al posicionarlo como `absolute` se pierden del flujo y sus coordenadas son relativas al elemento que lo contiene que este posicionado, como no tiene un elemento padre posicionado las coordenadas son relativas a la ventana. Podrías colocar las imagenes dentro de un `div` posicionado como `relative`.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "hd"
    "mn"
    "ft";
}

header {
  grid-area: hd;
}
main {
  grid-area: mn;
}
.container-image {
    position: relative;
    height: 750px;
    width: 100%;
}
.container-image img#img1 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 121;
}
.container-image img#img2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 137;
}
.container-image img#img3 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 140;
}
footer {
  grid-area: ft;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non
        placerat risus, in aliquet augue. Sed libero magna, sodales vel accumsan
        non, fringilla ac massa. Sed euismod rhoncus felis, sed ultricies metus
        consectetur ut. Etiam et felis a tortor feugiat sagittis id a ipsum. In
        consequat odio ut velit rutrum elementum. Nulla facilisi. Vivamus lacus
        turpis, viverra sed laoreet vel, tempus quis mi. Morbi a libero ac odio
        fermentum efficitur ut at est. Nulla id ex id orci ultrices ultrices.
        Suspendisse potenti. In ut nulla a sapien finibus interdum. Aenean
        feugiat eget urna vitae sodales. Nulla pharetra pharetra quam lacinia
        mattis. Vivamus pulvinar fringilla velit in viverra. Curabitur vel metus
        sed nunc pellentesque egestas vel ut nunc. Suspendisse potenti. Cras at
        urna vel metus pretium porttitor. Pellentesque eget iaculis mi.
        Phasellus id lacinia odio. Curabitur vitae sem in lacus semper sagittis.
        Etiam molestie sem quis nisl ornare, ut dictum orci luctus. Quisque
        rutrum elit metus, sed elementum diam maximus et. Aliquam ornare, odio
        at egestas pharetra, ligula tellus euismod nibh, vel semper ligula velit
        eget ante. Cras vel consequat magna. Pellentesque habitant morbi
        tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Duis
        eget nisi tortor. Sed et interdum leo. Integer tempus ex non tortor
        hendrerit vulputate ut volutpat lacus.
      </p>
    </header>
    <main>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non
        placerat risus, in aliquet augue. Sed libero magna, sodales vel accumsan
        non, fringilla ac massa. Sed euismod rhoncus felis, sed ultricies metus
        consectetur ut. Etiam et felis a tortor feugiat sagittis id a ipsum. In
        consequat odio ut velit rutrum elementum. Nulla facilisi. Vivamus lacus
        turpis, viverra sed laoreet vel, tempus quis mi. Morbi a libero ac odio
        fermentum efficitur ut at est. Nulla id ex id orci ultrices ultrices.
        Suspendisse potenti. In ut nulla a sapien finibus interdum. Aenean
        feugiat eget urna vitae sodales. Nulla pharetra pharetra quam lacinia
        mattis. Vivamus pulvinar fringilla velit in viverra. Curabitur vel metus
        sed nunc pellentesque egestas vel ut nunc. Suspendisse potenti. Cras at
        urna vel metus pretium porttitor. Pellentesque eget iaculis mi.
        Phasellus id lacinia odio. Curabitur vitae sem in lacus semper sagittis.
        Etiam molestie sem quis nisl ornare, ut dictum orci luctus. Quisque
        rutrum elit metus, sed elementum diam maximus et. Aliquam ornare, odio
        at egestas pharetra, ligula tellus euismod nibh, vel semper ligula velit
        eget ante. Cras vel consequat magna. Pellentesque habitant morbi
        tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Duis
        eget nisi tortor. Sed et interdum leo. Integer tempus ex non tortor
        hendrerit vulputate ut volutpat lacus.
      </p>
      <div class="container-image">
        <img
          src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/12/09/21/11/silhouette-5818603_960_720.jpg"
          id="img1"
        />
        <img
          src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/12/09/21/11/silhouette-5818603_960_720.jpg"
          id="img2"
        />
        <img
          src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/12/09/21/11/silhouette-5818603_960_720.jpg"
          id="img3"
        />
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non
        placerat risus, in aliquet augue. Sed libero magna, sodales vel accumsan
        non, fringilla ac massa. Sed euismod rhoncus felis, sed ultricies metus
        consectetur ut. Etiam et felis a tortor feugiat sagittis id a ipsum. In
        consequat odio ut velit rutrum elementum. Nulla facilisi. Vivamus lacus
        turpis, viverra sed laoreet vel, tempus quis mi. Morbi a libero ac odio
        fermentum efficitur ut at est. Nulla id ex id orci ultrices ultrices.
        Suspendisse potenti. In ut nulla a sapien finibus interdum. Aenean
        feugiat eget urna vitae sodales. Nulla pharetra pharetra quam lacinia
        mattis. Vivamus pulvinar fringilla velit in viverra. Curabitur vel metus
        sed nunc pellentesque egestas vel ut nunc. Suspendisse potenti. Cras at
        urna vel metus pretium porttitor. Pellentesque eget iaculis mi.
        Phasellus id lacinia odio. Curabitur vitae sem in lacus semper sagittis.
        Etiam molestie sem quis nisl ornare, ut dictum orci luctus. Quisque
        rutrum elit metus, sed elementum diam maximus et. Aliquam ornare, odio
        at egestas pharetra, ligula tellus euismod nibh, vel semper ligula velit
        eget ante. Cras vel consequat magna. Pellentesque habitant morbi
        tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Duis
        eget nisi tortor. Sed et interdum leo. Integer tempus ex non tortor
        hendrerit vulputate ut volutpat lacus.
      </p>
    </footer>
  </body>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!! Desconocia este dato 

Comment: Bueno, de nada.